# Manipulating datetime Python

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I want to convert a string into datetime, the string is parsed as such:

```
Metatime = datetime.datetime.strptime(metadata.get("FileModifyDate"), "%y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Where metadata.get returns something like this:

```
2012:11:19 14:53:44-05:00
```

I have another datatime element that I want to compare with, so the formating should be the same. The other datetime element is like this:

```
(datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 26, 23, 22, 21)
```

How can I format things to be able to do a logical comparison?

Comment: why you want to compare the strings and not the `datetime` objects?

Comment: ^ This. "How can I format things to be able to do a logical comparison?" By leaving them as datetime objects, and using logical comparison operators `<`, `==`, `>`...

Comment: metadata.get doesnt return a datetime, metadata is a json map, and 2012:11:19 14:53:44-05:00 is formated as a string

Comment: What is the meaning of the `-05:00` in the string returned from `metadata.get`?

Comment: yes, I also have no idea what it means, metadata.get is a function i made that calls exiftool to retrieve metadata from a file.

Comment: looks like a time zone offset

Comment: Do you have control over the format of the date? `dateutil` doesn't know how to parse this particular format. Also, keep in mind that you want to compare timezone-aware datetime with one that isn't timezone-aware.

Answer (score 0):

Python's standard datetime.strptime() method does not support parsing timezone info in hh:mm format.  There is an open [feature request](http://bugs.python.org/issue24954) for that.

Meanwhile, you can use the following work-around:

```
>>> FileModifyDate = '2012:11:19 14:53:44-05:00'
>>> datetime.strptime(FileModifyDate.replace(':', ''), '%Y%m%d %H%M%S%z')
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 19, 14, 53, 44, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 68400)))
>>> print(_)
2012-11-19 14:53:44-05:00
```

Note that you need to us Python version 3.3 or later for this to work.

Now, if you want to compare the result to

```
>>> another_date = datetime(2014, 3, 26, 23, 22, 21)
```

you need to know what timezone that date is in.  If it is in UTC - do

```
>>> file_date = datetime.strptime(FileModifyDate.replace(':', ''), '%Y%m%d %H%M%S%z')
>>> another_date.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) > file_date
True
```

If it is in some other zone, you will need to use a third party library such as pytz to convert it to an aware instance before you can compare.